# Dual boot with windows xp

Tags: dual-boot, hd-video

Now I'm using windows xp,but i just planned for ubuntu.Configeration of my pc is pentium 4 with 1gb of RAM.Is it good for dual boot?
Another thing is now I'm not able to play any hd Videos.After installing ubuntu can i able to play all this stuff?

Comment: Please separate your questions into separate posts.

Comment: of course you can. Just install it without any doubt.

Comment: @shantanu You may want to post this as an answer, perhaps somewhat expanded, with a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your PC is more than able to dual boot. Perhaps give a thought to Xubuntu, although I don't think that's necessary.

As for your second question -- HD is *demanding*. The fact that all newer PCs are able to effortlessly play it does not make it any less astoundingly resource intensive. Given your hardware, I estimate it's going to be difficult to get HD playing fluently. But -- that's no reason for not trying :)